# How to name a memory location (C++)?

Tags: c++, pointers

This is a question regarding pointers in C++.

The diagrams that follow use the following representation:

[image]

Let's say we have `int* k = 1778`. This is represented in the left diagram below. How do I name the memory location in `k`? This is marked by the question mark in the diagram on the right.

[image]

I understand that if I write `int x = *k`, a new memory location will get assigned as shown on the right below, so this does not accomplish the task.

[image]

Comment: `int* k = 150` is how I read this where presumably `1778` is in that memory location.

Comment: Memory address 1778 is not sufficiently aligned for `int` on systems where it has to be aligned to 4 bytes.

Comment: AS I understand the diagrams, the "?" represents the fact that there is no name. Please explain why that is not the answer to your question. I.e. what makes your think that the diagram intentionally skip an available piece of information, while their goal otherwise seems to be visualising some non-trival aspects of pointers in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable names are not a property of the memory location. Those names are used by the program for accessing relevant memory locations. So that you cannot name a memory location in the physical memory (RAM).

If you need to access the dereference(*) of the pointer k through a new name, please create a reference variable and assign the dereference of pointer k to created reference variable.

Example:

```
int& ref_k = *k;
```